# Converting JSON to specific string format

Tags: javascript, json

I get the following json data from server.

```
{"visits":[{"City":6,"Count":5},{"City":16,"Count":1},{"City":23,"Count":1},{"City":34,"Count":1}]}
```

and i need to convert it to following format:

```
{"1":"82700","2":"26480","3":"31530","4":"22820","5":"15550","6":"205790"}
```

I have the following code but not working out:

```
       var cities = "{";

        for (var key in data.visits) {
            var val = data.visits[key];
            //Now you have your key and value which you 
            //can add to a collection that your plugin uses
            var obj = {};
            obj[val.City] = '' + val.Count;

            var code = '' + val.City;
            var count = '' + val.Count;

            cities += code + ':' + count + ',';
        }

        cities += "}";
```

I need the integers in string representation and need to get rid of the final , .

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var data    = {"visits":[{"City":6,"Count":5},{"City":16,"Count":1},{"City":23,"Count":1},{"City":34,"Count":1}]};
var result = {};

for (var i = 0; i < data.visits.length; i++) {
  result[data.visits[i].City] = String(data.visits[i].Count);
}
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/gipaxa/4/edit?js,console)

Keys in object always converts to string you don't need convert it to string manually. If you need convert all object to JSON string you can use `JSON.stringify(result);`

Answer (score 1):

How I understood you want to create new json with given json.you can parse it,run with cycle on it,and create a new json whatever kind of you want.
here is a link which can help you.
http://www.w3docs.com/learn-javascript/working-with-json.html